# Should super class be abstract on Inheritance joined?

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0

I use Jpa 2 with Hibernate Provider.

I use inheritance of type `InheritanceType.JOINED`. My superclass should be abstract or not ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is matter of opinion, because according JPA 2.0 specification both abstract and concrete super classes are allowed also in the case of joined inheritance.

Most likely you do not have such a use case where you have to create instance of super class. That's why it makes sense to have it abstract, because it documents purpose of the class (not to be directly instantiated). Independently from class being abstract or not you can also create queries for super class type.

Answer (score 1):

Depends if you want to instantiate the Super class or now. Makes no difference as far as hibernate/jpa is concerned.